# Angular "apply" changes to watched scope property not triggering "watch" function

Tags: angularjs

In my angular directive.js I have defined the scope watch for a property 'appInfo' of the controller:

```
this.scope_.$watch('ctrl.appInfo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
```

And in the test case I'm setting a value for appInfo in the scope:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  scope.appInfo = [{
    language: 'English',
    name: 'AppName',
    description: 'description'
  }];
});
```

But when the above apply happens, the scope watch method in the directive doesn't get called. Can someone please help what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to angular js, so I must be doing something silly.

Answer (score 1):

you need to watch the specific attribute in the data that was changed.
ataching example where i'm changing the appInfo.num with interval and then I'm applying the apply you can see here the example. open the console and you will see it there
http://plnkr.co/edit/XGoLmDaSVkL6cEVQnkdh?p=preview[working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGoLmDaSVkL6cEVQnkdh?p=preview)

it's the controller

```
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', [])

   .controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       setInterval(function(){

         $scope.appInfo.num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
         $scope.$apply();
         }

         , 3000);

      $scope.appInfo = {
      language: 'English',
      name: 'AppName',
      description: 'description',
      num:1
  };

       $scope.$watch('appInfo.num', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log($scope.appInfo);
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your property is bound to the scope, not the controller. You can return the property as the first argument of the watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return $scope.appInfo;
  }, 
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('watch fired');
});
```

[See plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mryThqCh4d4VysLtfbi9?p=preview)